# Can I choose only some directories of Windows 2008 R2 if I want to backup Hyper-V using Windows Server Backup?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, windows-server-backup

I want to use `Windows Server Backup` that's included with Windows to backup Hyper-V. Can I only choose `C:\VM`, `E:\VM` and `C:\ProgramsData` (basically hyper-v directory I'm interested in) if that's where the Hyper-V machines reside? Or do I need to backup both C and E drives?